# how can I find the minimum distance between two point by using inheritance?

Tags: c++

I would like to return a pointer to the object for which the distance is smallest by using getDistanceTo() method from Shape.cpp. But my findClosestTo() method will be core dumped.
So how can I fix findClosestTo() method?

ShapeList.cpp

```
Shape* ShapeList::findClosestTo (double p_x, double p_y) const{
    Shape* distance = nullptr;
    for ( const auto& item : *this ) {
        double longest  = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        double previous = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        longest = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        if(previous > longest){
            distance = item;
        }
    }
    return distance;
}
```

ShapeList.h

```
class ShapeList : protected std::list<Shape*> {
public:
    ShapeList( ) = default;
    ~ShapeList();
    void add( Shape* newShape );
    void write( std::ostream& strm_out ) const;
    void erase();
    Shape* findClosestTo (double p_x, double p_y) const;

    friend std::ostream& operator<<( std::ostream& strm_out, const ShapeList& shapes );
};
```

main.cpp

```
cout << "test \"closest\" methods...\n";
double x;
double y;
cout << "Enter coordinates for search of closest object reference: ";
cin  >> x >> y;
cout << "x: " << x << " y: " << y << endl;
Shape* closestObj = shapes2.findClosestTo( x, y );
cout << "closestObj: " << *closestObj << endl;
if ( closestObj != nullptr )
    cout << "The object closest to the point provided is located at "
         << *closestObj << endl;
```

Shape.cpp

```
double Shape::getDistanceTo (double p_x, double p_y) const{
    double distance;
    distance = sqrt(p_x * ref_x + p_y * ref_y);
    return distance;
}
```

Comment: First tell us whats wrong with it

Comment: What does the line `distance` above the `for` statement do?  Since there is no terminating semicolon, the compiler is treating this as `distance for ...`

Comment: Why are you calculating `longest` twice in `findClosestTo()`?  The declaration calculates and assigns a value.  After defining `previous`, the `longest` is calculated again, with the same equation.

Comment: In the same function, both `longest` and `previous` use the *exact same function call*.  The comparison should always be equal, unless something weird happens with the floating point representation.

Comment: I highly recommend not inheriting from `std::list`.  I suggest changing the concept to *shape list contains a container of shapes*.  In other words, the ShapeList has a container (a.k.a. vector or list) of shapes.

Comment: dont vandalise your answer just because you want to remove the source code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see a few problems. First:

```
Shape* ShapeList::findClosestTo (double p_x, double p_y) const{
    Shape* distance = nullptr;
    for ( const auto& item : *this ) {
        double longest  = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        double previous = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        longest = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        if(previous > longest){
            distance = item;
        }
    }
    return distance;
}
```

This method doesn't work because longest and previous both have the same value each time you loop. They're both calculated each time you loop. You need slightly different logic. There are a dozen different ways you can do this.

I might do this:

```
Shape* ShapeList::findClosestTo (double p_x, double p_y) const{
    Shape* closest = nullptr;
    double distanceToClosest = 0;

    for ( const auto& item : *this ) {
        double distance  = item->getDistanceTo(p_x, p_y);
        if(closest == nullptr || distance < distanceToClosest) {
            closest = item;
            distanceToClosest = distance;
        }
    }
    return closest;
}
```

Note that I renamed your variables to make it clearer what I was doing.

Next, this:

```
distance = sqrt(p_x * ref_x + p_y * ref_y);
```

That's a VERY strange way to calculate distance to p_x.

Try this. Note that you didn't show us Shape.h, so I'm making an assumption:

```
double Shape::getDistanceTo (double p_x, double p_y) const{
    double deltaX = this->x - p_x;
    double deltaY = this->y - p_y;
    double distance = sqrt(deltaX * deltaX + deltaY * deltaY);
    return distance;
}
```

I have no idea what your version of calculating a distance was trying to do.

I don't know why you're having other troubles, but I saw these. If you make some fixes then let us know what your code looks like and what line it's core dumping on, that will help.